# AspNet Core Route Mapping with different Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am currently working on a project in which I want to use on server for two different purposes, a test mode and a published mode. I am using AspNet core and the middleware pipeline to try to accomplish this. I want something along the lines of anything "/Test" in the url to do one thing and everything else to do the other mode. Normally I know how to solve these issues because AspNet Core middleware allows mapping to paths with app.Map("/Test", ...) but the problem with this is they both use the same pipeline, just different dependency injection/IoC container. From what I see the ConfigureServices method runs before the Configure method and has no configuration for per request paths on what services to use. So I just need a way to have the same pipeline but different requests use different Services for the IoC Container.

Comment: You could probably create a second `ServiceCollection` for your `/Test` routes. Not sure if it’s possible to automatically inject that for a subpath though.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest you trying to do it this way, you just make your job harder.

Instead rather use what ASP.NET Core offers you: Environment specific configurations. For that you'd be required to run two different applications, but the setup can still be in the same project, you just change the environment variable.

For this you first need a `launchSettings.json` with the settings.

Example from the documentation

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40088/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Staging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the Environment is set to "Staging". Next you need to define a configuration for it.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;

namespace Environments
{
    public class StartupStaging
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWelcomePage();
        }
    }
}

namespace Environments
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWelcomePage();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when your environment is set to `Production`, the `Startup` class will be called (or `StartupProduction` if existing). If your environment variable is set to `Staging`, the `StartupStaging` will be called.

As for the different urls... In your production application, you set it to

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://example.com/",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

and your test environment

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://example.com/Test/",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

Code/Configuration Snippets are taken from the [ASP.NET Core Docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html). Or just use the `hosting.json` for different environments.

`hosting.json`

```
{
  "server": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "server.urls": "http://example.com/"
}
```

On top of my head I think you can also have multiple files called `hosting.production.json` etc.